# Div's "creating" scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of different images, and when you hover the images I display a custom tooltip which sets itself just under the cursor.

Now, the tooltips works fine, but if I make the window big, hover an image on the edge and then make the window small again, so the tooltip div is outside the body, it creates a scrollbar (horizontal).

Or if the window is small enough so the tooltip gets outside of it, it also creates a scrollbar (thought this is fixable by some javascript checks)

Basicly I'm asking if there is any way of making a div "not create a scrollbar" or calling a function on window resizing?

[JSFiddle showing what's happening](http://jsfiddle.net/RTSvw/2/)

HTML

```
<div style='position:relative;'>
    <div class='img' onmousemove="showTooltip('tip', event);" onmouseout="hideTooltip('tip');"></div>
    <div id='tip' class='tooltip'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
.tooltip {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#888;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JS

```
function showTooltip(name, event) {
    var div = document.getElementById(name);
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
    div.style.top = (event.clientY + 20 + document.body.scrollTop) + "px";
    div.style.left = (event.clientX + 20 + document.body.scrollLeft) + "px";
}

function hideTooltip(name) {
    document.getElementById(name).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the hideTooltip funciton;

```
function hideTooltip(name) {
    var div = document.getElementById(name);
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    div.style.top = "0px";
    div.style.left = "0px";
}
```

This will ensure that no tooltip will be outside the window.

Comment: 1+ Nice solution - glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in your CSS to prevent scrolling. In this case since you don't have anything wrapping your area you'd have to apply it to the body.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in yous css should do just the thing. You might consider showing the tooltip on the other side of the image if your tooltip will move out of view